# Realtek Bluetooth 5.1 Radio driver doesn't load automatically

Tags: drivers, 22.04, bluetooth, realtek

I have a Bluetooth usb adapter

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, linux version `5.15.0-58-generic`, release 22.04, codename *jammy*

`Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth 5.1 Radio`

I found from the installation disk that needs the drivers: `rtl8723d`, `rtl8822b`, `rtl8821c`, `rtl8822c`and `rtl8761b`. The driver is not detected and each time to be loaded I take out the adapter and put it back in the usb port and then finally works. How I am going to do this automatically, without plug-out and plug-in the Bluetooth usb adapter?

```
;
;    Btfilter.INF
;--*/
[Version]
Signature   = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Bluetooth
CLASSGUID={e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
CatalogFile= RtkFilter.cat
Provider    = %REALTEK%
DriverVer = 06/24/2019,1.6.1015.3008
;*************************
; Source file information
;*************************
[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskId1%,,,""
[SourceDisksFiles]
PidVid_List.dll         = 1
RtkBtfilter.sys         = 1,,
RtkBtManServ.exe    = 1,,      ;RtkServ
rtl8723d_mp_chip_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch_new.dll             =   1
rtl8822b_mp_chip_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch_new.dll             =   1
rtl8821c_mp_chip_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch_new.dll             =   1
rtl8822c_mp_chip_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch_new.dll             =   1
rtl8761b_mp_chip_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch_new.dll             =   1
```

My Realtek drivers in `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt`

```
rtl8192ee_fw.bin               rtl8761b_fw.bin       rtl8822cs_fw.bin
rtl8192eu_fw.bin               rtl8761bu_config.bin  rtl8822cu_config.bin
rtl8723a_fw.bin                rtl8761bu_fw.bin      rtl8822cu_fw.bin
rtl8723b_fw.bin                rtl8812ae_fw.bin      rtl8852au_config.bin
rtl8723bs_config-OBDA0623.bin  rtl8821a_config.bin   rtl8852au_fw.bin
rtl8723bs_config-OBDA8723.bin  rtl8821a_fw.bin       rtl8852bu_config.bin
rtl8723bs_fw.bin               rtl8821c_config.bin   rtl8852bu_fw.bin
rtl8723d_config.bin            rtl8821c_fw.bin       rtl8852cu_config.bin
rtl8723d_fw.bin                rtl8822b_config.bin   rtl8852cu_fw.bin
rtl8761a_fw.bin                rtl8822b_fw.bin
rtl8761b_config.bin            rtl8822cs_config.bin
```

Edit: Running with `sudo dmesg |nc termbin.com 9999`

```
[    1.491813] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth 5.1 Radio
[    4.936135] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.936139] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.936143] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.162565] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.162770] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.162772] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.162776] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.162779] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.162785] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.951854] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x09a98a6b
[    4.240682] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[    4.246827] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    4.246835] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[    4.247727] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[    4.247857] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 27814
[    4.936135] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.936139] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.936143] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.951854] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x09a98a6b
[    6.877350] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.877361] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.877369] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, linux version `5.15.0-58-generic`, release `22.04`, codename `jammy`

Comment: The only relative with the `'blue|firm'` abbreviation as highlighted text is `bluetooth` the rest are just modules.

Comment: Yes, in one line.

Comment: I edited my answer. I have also a wireless keyboard and mouse. I suppose these are different Bluetooth usb devices.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how but now it works. It's not necessary to take out and put back the usb bluetooth adapter.